# How can I find out what is the driver for device node '/dev/video11'

Tags: linux

In linux kernel, a device (e.g. camera) can register as a file (e.g. `/dev/video11`).
How can I find out from the code which driver is registered as `/dev/video11`.
i.e. what is the driver will be invoked when I `open('/dev/video11', O_RDWR,0)` in my user space code?

If I can only search within the code space, how can I find out which
driver is for `/dev/video11`?

Is there a config file which I can look it up?

Comment: A device driver is a bunch of functions. It doesn't necessarily have a name.

Comment: If the code open('/dev/video11', O_RDWR,0), what is the corresponding driver code get executed? that Is what I would like to know. Thank you.

Comment: Back to square one. *A device driver is a bunch of functions*. How do you distinguish a bunch of functions from another bunch of functions?

Comment: I don't know. I would like help to answer that question. I am studying android source code.
From here,  it has code which open("/dev/video11", O_RDWR, 0) as
decoding device.

http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r1/xref/hardware/samsung_slsi/exynos5/libhwjpeg/ExynosJpegBase.cpp

I want to find out which is the corresponding driver code for device
'/dev/video11'.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry, I lied :( My kernel knowledge is somewhat outdated. Device drivers do have names. Look under `/sys/bus/*/driver`. If it's a USB camera you are likely to find it under `/sys/bus/usb/driver`. Then the name is generally the same as the directory name in which driver sources live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout a very similar [question on the Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45267/what-driver-is-behind-a-certain-device-file).

For your device, parsing the output of this command may help.

```
$  udevadm info -a -n /dev/video11
```